# Can Rebel Alliance Snowspeeder Launch Bay affect vehicles outside combat?

Tags: star-wars-lcg

I was recently playing a "pure" Rebel Alliance deck. I happened to put my Snowspeeder Launch Bay (from the Battle of Hoth set) into play and also got one of my Snowspeeders (from either the Desolation of Hoth set or the Battle of Hoth set) into play. I put the Snowspeeder up to attack.

My opponent put up a Heavy Stormtrooper Squad to fight me. He had a TIE Attack Squadron back in his play area.

I won edge and thus inflicted one damage on his trooper and one damage on the target engaged objective, but lost my Snowspeeder to his trooper.

Afterwards I re-read the text of my hanger bay:

> "**Reaction:** After you strike with a ***Speeder*** unit, deal 1
>   damage to a target enemy ***Vehicle*** unit. If the target is a
>   ***Walker*** unit, also place 1 focus token on it. (Limit once per phase.)"

I noticed the lack of the words *target participating enemy unit*. Since participating wasn't mentioned, this let me to believe that the target Vehicle can be targetted outside of combat as well. If this is true, I could damage my opponents TIE Attack Squadron as well, causing it one damage due to the reaction from the Snowspeeder Launch Bay.

Does this make sense? Is it legal? Or can this reaction only apply to units in combat?

Anyone play this card in any tournaments? Do you know the ruling on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far all my searching of forums has yielded only one result. Apparently someone asked the same question on boardgamegeek and received the following answer:

> "Yes, the vehicle doesn't need to be in the engagement for the Speeder Bay's ability to take effect."

Meaning, that yes, my speeder should have been able to damage the TIE Attack Squadron.

See post on [boardgamegeek](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1028134/snowspeeder-launch-bay-targets).

Comment: That is hardly an offical answer. Have you tried the FFG forums to see if a FFG representative will answer?